# Can I make a Wifi router using an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, wifi

Basically, I need to make at least 2 Arduino to communicate with each other via WIFI. I have brought some Wemos D1 (which similar to an arduino with built-in Wifi shield) and my task is to make a client and server communication without any (real and big)router in between. After a few weeks of "googling", I found every examples of wifi communication required router in between. So, I decided to make an Arduino wifi router, is it possible?

Thanks A Million. :)

Comment: You wifi module must be capable of acting like a WAP (wireless acces point)

Comment: Oh My God... What a solid answer... I dont think my Wemos is a WAP... Thanks A lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found this quite useful after some time, and Wemos D1 is a WAP

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/esp8266-thing-hookup-guide/example-sketch-ap-web-server